# How write search query for Sumologic to find stored ingest budget?

Tags: sumologic

I have a requirement to find Sumologic Ingest budget data via a search and then schedule it. Any idea which _index I should be using for this ?
I did search all the sumologic document but couldnt find concrete material to get this through.
Anyone with any ideas please direct me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
_index=sumologic_audit _sourceName=VOLUME_QUOTA _sourceCategory=account_management "Budget" "last reset" "Approaching"
```

or similar

taken from [the Sumo Logic docs on Managing Ingestion Volume](https://help.sumologic.com/Manage/Ingestion-and-Volume/Ingest_Budgets#Audit_ingest_budgets)

---

Disclaimer: I am currently employed by Sumo Logic

Comment: Thanks @ Grzegorz Oledzki ....... I had tried that from Sumo Docs but that ones doesnt come up with Ingest budget names. I was more concerned about the names

Comment: When I try, I see messages like this: `Budget analytics with scope _sourcecategory=analytics* consumed 85.00% of capacity since last reset.`
The second word here is the name of the budget

Comment: Okay gotcha .... But can we display it in columnar form?

Comment: You can use the "transpose" operator to form columns.